# Showing $A\times B\cong B\times A$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, direct-product

If I have two group, $A,B$, I want to prove that $A\times B\cong B\times A$. So my guess is to define a mapping $$\varphi:A\times B\rightarrow B\times A$$ $$\varphi((a,b))=(b,a)$$.

I must first show that $\varphi$ is well defined, which is pretty clear I think.  If we have that $\varphi((a,b))=(b,a)$ and $\varphi((a,b))=(b',a')$, we must have that $b=b'$ and $a=a'$ and so $\varphi$ is well defined.

It is a homomorphism since for elements $(a_1,b_1),(a_2,b_2)\in A\times B$

$$\begin{align}
\varphi((a_1,b_1)(a_2,b_2)) &=&\varphi((a_1a_2,b_1b_2)) \\
&=& (b_1b_2,a_1a_2) \\
&=& (b_1,a_1)(b_2,a_2) \\
&=& \varphi((a_1,b_1))\varphi((a_2,b_2))
\end{align}$$

And so we know $\varphi$ is a homomorphism.

Now, surjection is easy since clearly for all $b\in B, a\in A$ and $(b,a)\in B\times A$, we will always have an element in $A\times B$ where $\varphi((a,b))=(b,a)$ since we are just reversing the order of the direct product.

Finally, it is injective since if we know $\varphi((a_1,b_1))=\varphi((a_2,b_2))$, then we have that $(b_1,a_1)=(b_2,a_2)$ which means $a_1=a_2$ and $b_1=b_2$.

Since now $\varphi$ is both injective and surjective, it is bijective, and is also a homomorphism, then we have that $A\times B\cong B\times A$.

Is this a corrrect proof?  I was curious of the well defined portion as well defined always gives me issues.

Comment: Well-definedness is usually only a problem if quotient structures come into play.

Comment: All is fine, but as $\varphi\circ\varphi$ is the identity, then it's plain that $\varphi$ is a bijection.

Comment: @Wuestenfux, is that because the objects of the mappings then are Cosets which then themselves have multiple elements?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown, why is that so?

Comment: Actually one my $\varphi$s isn't a $\varphi$ but never mind. The point is that mapping $(b,a)$ to $(a,b)$ inverts the map $\varphi$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Except that the two $\phi$ in your $\phi\circ\phi$ are different homomorphisms, but yes, we have an obvious two-sided inverse

Comment: I think you are correct, and I don't know what to answer XD

Comment: Well-definedness is just a fancy way to say it's a legitimate function: That if $x_1 = x_2$, then $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$. So right, when we define maps whose inputs and outputs are cosets, we usually define them using a representative from the coset. There's a danger that $\varphi(gN)$ depends on which $g' \in gN$ we pick to define it, and the map is "well-defined" when $\varphi$ *doesn't* depend on the representatives chosen (you can see it fail by trying to define the usual multiplication on a particular set of cosets $G/H$ when $H$ isn't normal in $G$; the multiplication isn't well-defined).

Comment: Thak you everybody!  I appreciate it.